# asp.net gridview pagination not displayed until refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have a `DataGridView` on a page. When I call that page whole list comes. I have decided to add pagination to the `GridView`.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_Del" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_Sel"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="id" Visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="Author" SortExpression="author" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="active" />
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" SelectText="Delete"  ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>



//Page_Load()
gridFill();
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PageSize = 10;
```

`gridFill()` method fills the `GridView`.

```
public void gridFill()
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/inetpub/example.com/db/db.mdb");
    sql = "SELECT  id, name, author, active, FROM [table]";
    dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
        comm= new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        da= new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);

        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Error: ";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

When I call the page it still gets all the rows at once. Also if I click 11th or later (because I limit the paging to 10 rows) rows for deleting I get index error.

So I have added another `Button` labeled as 'Refresh' which calls gridFill() method once more. Then pagination gets valid.

What could be the reason for GridView not paging for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the order of the lines

```
//Page_Load()
gridFill();
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PageSize = 10;
```

to

```
//Page_Load()
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PageSize = 10;
gridFill();
```

it works. I can't believe it

Comment: Well, it works because in your `gridFill()`, the `DataBind()` method uses the GridView's properties, like `AllowPaging` and `PageSize`. If you set them AFTER binding, `DataBind()` uses default values.